Behavior Tree tick rate exceeded
OS: Ubuntu Jammy (22.04) with ROS 2 Humble installed via binary
Nav2 installation: via binaries
I have been noting that whenever I send a NavigateToPose goal, I seem to get spammed on the console with the following warning:
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.727192627] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.747837726] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.765588186] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.779422265] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.820577297] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.856457061] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.866001725] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.886925505] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.936222778] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-16] [WARN] [1722937805.981416400] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!

This does not hamper the execution of the goal, it simply spams the console with the message. I was able to trace it down to this section of the behavior tree engine node.
I have the following questions about this phenomenon:

Is there anything I can do to not have this warning?
If people have encountered this before, have you figured out the source? What could lead the behavior tree engine node to exceed this loop rate?
I see here in the main branch that this warning has been replaced by a debug message. This brings me to my final question: is it okay to safely ignore this warning if nothing else works?


We encountered something similar, and fixed it with this PR.
This hasn't been released yet for humble, could you compile the latest humble version and test if it also fixes your warnings?

Thanks for your answer. I tried compiling the latest humble version from source, however, the issue persists. I'd love to know if you have any other pointers/ideas.
